# Create Map from Elements from List of case class

Tags: scala

```
      case class Student(id:String, name:String, teacher:String )
      val myList = List( Student("1","Ramesh","Isabela"), Student("2","Elena","Mark"),Student("3","invalidKey","Someteacher"))
      
      val a = myList.foreach( i=> (i.name ->  i.teacher)).toMap.filter(i.name != "invalidKey")
```

I have a list of case class of student. I Want to build a map of student, teacher which are name ( key of the map) will always be unique. Preferably map can filter out a certain name.

Comment: Add a `toMap` at the end. and remove the `println`

Comment: You can use `collect` instead of `map` + `filter`

Comment: I am not getting the elements from the iterator i . Thats the issue

Comment: Well, because you are using a `foreach` instead of a `map` if you check the type signatures and read the docs it shouñd be clear why that won't work: https://www.scala-lang.org/api/current/scala/collection/immutable/List.html - Anyways, all you need is this: https://scastie.scala-lang.org/BalmungSan/mEEDnPQ0TcWAwE8lcz9EIg/2

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You're using foreach, which returns Unit as the result.
I would suggest either of these 2 below. First one is as Luis Miguel mentioned:

```scala
val myMap = myList.collect {
  case student if student.name != "invalidKey" => student.name -> student.teacher
}.toMap
```

Or:

```scala
val myMap2 = myList.foldLeft[Map[String, String]](Map.empty) {
  case (elementsMap, newElement) if newElement.name != "invalidKey" => 
    elementsMap + (newElement.name -> newElement.teacher)
  case (elementsMap, _) => elementsMap
}
```

Differences:

First approach is much easier to read and shorter (being shorter is not an advantage though :D). Second one has less iterations (first one has another iteration to convert to Map).

Comment: You can just add a `view` before `collect` and now the first one only iterates once... but it may actually be slower for small collections; premature optimizations are the root of all evil.

Comment: By the way, what I meant by "has one less iteration" is not that it has a better algorithm order in terms of time complexity, they're both considered to be O(n).

Comment: @LuisMiguelMejíaSuárez, I took a look and at views, and also read some versions of actual source codes, and found out that this pretty much depends on the implementation of SeqView. In some versions the view contains the type constructor, and when you want to convert the list to map, the view is forced to evaluate (resulting in List[...]), and then is converted to map (that one extra iteration). and in newer versions, view gets rid of type constructor, and converting to map is done using `Map.from(iterable)` (I'm not sure if this has the extra iteration). (rest of the comment in the next one).

Comment: In both cases (both implementations), I think the second approach (folding) would take less than or equal to the first one (view). Am I right?

Comment: Yeah `Views` before `2.13` are mostly useless, I basically ignore their existence before `2.13` and yes, the `foldLeft` should always be at least as efficient, although. But again, to actually answer that one must properly benchmark, is best to optimize readability and only care about performance when it really matters.

Comment: @LuisMiguelMejíaSuárez, I agree, I recently posted a question on [codereview stackexchange](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/questions/276105/batching-method-implementation-scala) which is concerned about this exact topic (readability, etc...). Can you please take a look?

Comment: For that question, I would probably first look if **fs2** provides something if not, I would use `State` and `traverse` from **cats**.